# The uniform metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given the definition of uniform metric on $R^J$:  $p(x,y):= \sup(d(x_α,y_α)|α \in J)$ where $d$ is the standard bounded metric. I want to know how to check if $p$ is a metric. I thought that the whole thing is really trivial as it consists of the standard bounded metric so it's immediate that the uniform metric is a metric. However, if I want to break down it's a metric how should I elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried checking the axioms?

Comment: What is $R^J$? Also, what do you mean by the "standard bounded metric"?

Comment: @user759562 $\Bbb R^J$ and the standard bounded metric on $\Bbb R$ is $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$, which is bounded above by $1$.

Comment: @G.Chiusole The first 3 axioms (nonegativity,definiteness,symmetry)were easy to check given the fact that d is a metric. Not sure how to show it for the  triangle inequality property.

Answer (score 1):

$p(x,x)=0$ because the sup of $\{0\}$ is $0$. And a sup of numbers that are $\ge 0$ is always $\ge 0$ too. The sup is well-defined as the set of distances is bounded above by $1$.

If $p(x,y)=0$ for some $x,y \in \Bbb R^J$. Assume $x \neq y$ so there is some coordinate $\alpha \in J$ such that $x_\alpha \neq y_\alpha$ and then $d(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)>0$, as $d$ is a metric. But then $p(x,y) \ge d(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)>0$ too, contradicting $p(x,y)=0$. Hence $x=y$.

For all $\alpha \in J$, d(x_\alpha, y_\alpha) = d(y_\alpha, x_\alpha)$ so for $p(x,y) and $p(y,x)$ we take the sup of the same set and so they are equal.

Let $x,y,z$ be three points of $\Bbb R^J$.

For each $\alpha \in J$: $$d(x_\alpha, z_\alpha) \le d(x_\alpha, y_\alpha) + d(y_\alpha, z_\alpha) \le p(x,y)+p(y,z)$$

So that $p(x,y)+p(y,z)$ is an upperbound for the set $\{d(x_\alpha, z_\alpha): \alpha \in J\}$ and $p(x,z)$ is the *least* upper bound for that set by definition hence

$$p(x,z) \le p(x,y)+p(y,z)$$

as required.